# RIGHT function Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I don't understand why this formula isn't working with this cells? For other columns I tried and works. What I'm doing wrong?

Formula:

```
=RIGHT(D5;10)
```

What Excel is bringing up: `0070717593`

What I need: `2017-09-01`

`D4` cell string: `2017-09-01 00:10:11`

Comment: `RIGHT()` is not the right function to extract the date if the cell is formatted as text, use either `LEFT()` or `TEXTBEFORE()` or `TEXTSPLIT()` however if the cell is not formatted as text then `INT()` function would work.

Comment: The formula is working as it should. Excel stores date/times as days and fractions of days since `1-Jan-1900`. `2019-09-01 00:10:11` is stored as `42979.0070717593` (and formatted to show a date time as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. The right ten characters are `0070717593` which is exactly what is shown.  To extract the date, use `INT`, as mentioned by @MayukhBhattacharya and then format the results how you wish.

Answer (score 2):

As I have commented above to explain this more clearly, I am posting it here with some screenshots.

1. If the cells are not formatted as text then, use <kbd>INT()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=INT(A1)
```

---

2. Or, If the cells are not formatted as text or if formatted as text then, use <kbd>TEXTBEFORE()</kbd> or <kbd>TEXTSPLIT()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1,".")/1
```

---

Or, in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=@TEXTSPLIT(A1,".")+0
```

---

3. Or, If the cells are not formatted as text or if formatted as text then then, use <kbd>LEFT()</kbd> with <kbd>FIND()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1)*1
```

---

Now, here comes the question, why you shouldn't be using the <kbd>RIGHT()</kbd> to extract the date,

> *As in Excel’s Date and Time values are stored as floating-point*
> *numbers, with the whole number representing the number of days since*
> *1st January 1900 and the fractional part representing the time of day*
> *as a fraction of 24 hours. This allows Excel to perform various*
> *calculations with ease, making it highly useful for business and*
> *scientific purposes.*

---

Here is what you are getting using <kbd>RIGHT()</kbd> which should be avoided as <kbd>INT()</kbd> function dedicatedly extracts the date, bt there are other functions like I have shown which can be used. From the screenshot below you can see when you select the cell <kbd>A2</kbd> and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> or click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to open format cells and select as Category Number it turns into a floating point numbre, so it is clear they are not stored as text, if its in `TEXT` format, then you can use one of the formulas as shown above.

[image]

---

**Also note:** When using those **`TEXT`** functions like <kbd>LEFT</kbd> or <kbd>TEXTSPLIT()</kbd> or <kbd>TEXTBEFORE()</kbd> i have either added with `0` or multiplied with `1` or divided by `1` so as to convert them to a number as the return is a text, also you can add double unary `--` before the formula, which does the same. Hope it explains well !

---

Edit : In addition to the **`Clause`** if formatted as text then:

[image]

---

• In cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1," ")+0
```

---

Or, in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=@TEXTSPLIT(A2," ")/1
```

---

Or, in cell <kbd>B3</kbd>

```
=LEFT(A3,FIND(" ",A3)-1)*1
```

---

**Notes:** Solutions posted above assumes the cells or the range of cells do not have any **`non-printable characters`**, in that scenarios the formulas may differ slightly to parse those characters. Usually the non-printable offending characters codes are `160`, `127` etc which can be removed using <kbd>SUBSTITUTE()</kbd> function. That said, then

```
=INT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160),)/1)
```

---

Or,

```
=TEXTBEFORE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160),),".")+0
```

---